# Child setState causing parent/entire app to refresh in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `button`, a `function` and a `state` all within `Dashboard.js`, show just below.

```
//Dashboard.js

<button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(snippet)}>EDIT</button>
```

Which calls this function

```
//Dashboard.js

  handleOpenModal = snippet => {
    this.setState(
      {
        sid: snippet._id,
        name: snippet.name,
        details: snippet.details,
        content: snippet.content,
      },
      () => this.showModal.current.showModal()
    )
  }
```

Which sets the state, and creates a `ref`.

```
//Dashboard.js

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showModal = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      snippets: [],
      sid: '',
      name: '',
      details: '',
      content: '',
    }
  }
```

The `ref` is passed to a `Modal.js` component

```
//Dashboard.js

        <Modal
          ref={this.showModal}
          sid={this.state.sid}
          name={this.state.name}
          details={this.state.details}
          content={this.state.content}
          handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          handleContentChange={this.handleContentChange}
          handleUpdateDashboard={this.handleUpdateDashboard}
        />
```

---

The Modal has a state containing a boolean, two functions and a ternary operator.

`showModal` is triggered by the `ref` passed from within the parent `Dashboard.js` when you click the button. Sets `isVisible` to true. This works seamlessly. The modal opens instantly without any refresh/reload. Works as intended.

`hideModal`, however, is triggered by the button at the bottom of the `Modal.js` component. It sets `isVisible` to false. This closes the modal but is then quickly follow by the a quick flash of what seems to be the entire App refreshing. And I can't figure out why/how this is happening. It makes the experience feel clunky.

```
//Modal.js

export default class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false,
    }
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true })
  }
  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: false })
  }
  render() {
    const handleUpdateDashboard = this.props.handleUpdateDashboard
    return (
      <div
        id="Modal"
        style={{ display: this.state.isVisible === true ? 'flex' : 'none' }}
      >
        //
        //Modal content
        //
        <button onClick={() => this.hideModal()}>CLOSE</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding `type="button"` at the "CLOSE" button as you have on the "EDIT" button. Looks like you get your form submitted. Or use the event passed by onClick and call `preventDefault()` on it.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Hit the nail on the head. Moving the button out of the form fixed the issue.